# Xcode 6 simulator renames ApplicationID (not DeviceID) for each run

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6, nsdocumentdirectory

I've read a bunch of threads that talk about paths to the documents directory changing with each run of the simulator, but the discussion is about the DeviceID, which I agree isn't changing.  What is changing is the ApplicationID and at least using the method I am to find it, I can't find it on the next run so my sql db isn't there.

Here's and example of what I'm seeing:

First run:
     Documents directory: /Users/annewest/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9DE1C194-BFB1-47CA-9CA1-77FA89F43960/data/Containers/Data/Application/4EFF7925-BB9E-4D9F-BD8C-B5BF44361189/Documents

I then stop the app in Xcode and run again.  Now I see

Second run:
     Documents directory: /Users/annewest/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9DE1C194-BFB1-47CA-9CA1-77FA89F43960/data/Containers/Data/Application/8409664B-8EF4-4318-A6D7-EB07E965F0F6/Documents

Note the DEviceID, the first random string, is the same, but the ApplicationID is changed.

Here's the code I'm using to find the directory and file path and create the persistent store coordinator:

```
- (NSString *) documentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Documents directory%@", documentsDirectory);
    return documentsDirectory;
}

- (NSString *) dataStorePath
{
    return [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataStore.sqlite"];
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (!_persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self dataStorePath]];
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

        NSError *error;
        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error adding persistent store %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Can someone with more knowledge than I help sort this out?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

After poking around for an hour, here's what I discovered:

Having a different ApplicationID is fine; the system just seems to rename the directory but the contents stay the same.  I was being fooled by Lyra, which couldn't find the original directory.